# Saving the auth token and using it

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, gamesparks

Having trouble figuring out how to save the auth token from the authorization request response and use it for making an authorized request so that I can pull database information. Appreciate any advice!

When I run $node index on the code below, I get this status 403 response.

```html
$ node index
STATUS: 403
STATUS: 200
HEADERS: {"x-gs-rid":"notsureifthisinfoisconfidentialornot","content-type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","cache-control":"no-ca
che, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","pragma":"no-cache","expires":"0","strict-transport-security":"max-age=31536000 ; inc
ludeSubDomains, max-age=15768000","x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block","x-frame-options":"DENY","x-content-type-options":"nosniff"
,"connection":"close","set-cookie":["mesosphere_server_id=notsureifthisprivatetoo; path=/"]}
BODY: {"country":"US","username":"myemailaddress","expiresAt":1511230469149,"X-GSAccessToken":"LotsofNumbersandLettersandPeriodsforTokenGoeshere"}
```

My issue is that I'm trying to save this auth token and use it properly so that I can make the next request(that's now authorized) to config2.gamesparks.net databases but can't figure out how.

```html
var config     = require( "./config.json" );

var gameSparks = require( "./GameSparks" );

var https = require('https');
var options = {
  host: 'auth.gamesparks.net',
  path: '/restv2/auth/user',
  headers: {
      'Authorization':'Basic PRIVATEGSAUTHCODEHERE'
  }
};

var req = https.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

  // Buffer the body entirely for processing as a whole.
  var bodyChunks = [];
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    // You can process streamed parts here...
    bodyChunks.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', function() {
    var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
    console.log('BODY: ' + body);
    // ...and/or process the entire body here.
  })
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
});

var gsrequest = {
  host: 'config2.gamesparks.net',
  path: '/restv2/game/GSAPIKEYHEREcipm/endpoints/',
  }
};
var req = https.get(gsrequest, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
});
```

Comment: is your PRIVATEGSAUTHCODE base64 encoded?  Does it expect a user:token encoded with user being anything?

Comment: yes it is and sorry I have no idea, i'm running blind over here.

Answer (score 2):

If what you are posting is JSON, then it looks like the access-token is accessible via

```
body.X-GSAccessToken
```